# Ansible: Fetch variable value from inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am having issues fetching the value of `ansible_user` under `rhel` from the inventory file. Below are the few ways that I tried to fetch, everytime it says undefined `rhel`. Any suggestions as to how to retrieve it?

```
    - set_fact:
         SSHUSER: "{{  hostvars.[rhel].ansible_user }}"
```

```
    - set_fact:
         SSHUSER: "{{  rhel.ansible_user }}"
```

```
---
all:
  vars:
    project: test
  hosts:
  children:
    test_vm:
       hosts: 10.10.10.4
    example_vm:
       hosts: 10.10.10.5
    ubuntu:
      children:
        test_vm:
      vars:
        os: ubuntu
        ansible_user: "testuser"
    rhel:
      children:
        example_vm:
      vars:
        os: rhel
        ansible_user: "exampleuser"
```

Comment: The `rhel` you are referencing is a **group**, not a host -- a host may belong to multiple groups. The expression you'd want is "the hostvars of some member of the group `rhel`" which is expressed as `{{ hostvars[groups["rhel"][0]].ansible_user }}`

Comment: @mdaniel what does [0] represent here?

Comment: @Eva, since a group usually has several members represented in a list of of members, `[0]` defines a list element. Here it will be the first entry.

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks it worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rhel` you are referencing is a *group*, not a host -- a host may belong to multiple groups. The expression you'd want in order to achieve "the hostvars of some member of the group rhel" is the jinja2 expression: `{{ hostvars[groups["rhel"][0]].ansible_user }}`

Where `groups["rhel"]` are the list of strings of ansible inventory hostnames, and if one presumes they all have an equivalent `ansible_user` then it should be safe to just grab the first one, which is `groups["rhel"][0]` or the more verbose but perhaps clearer `groups["rhel"]|first`

Then, we want the `hostvars` for *that host*, not our own; since `hostvars` is a `dict[str, dict]` indexed by the ansible inventory hostname, we can plug that value into the `hostvars` dict as `hostvars[groups["rhel"][0]]` which is every hostvar, and then `hostvars[groups["rhel"][0]].ansible_user` gives back the `ansible_user` fact you requested